# What is a provider in terms of omniauth?

Tags: omniauth

When the [docs](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth) refer to provider, is it referring to the Resource Provider, or the Doorkeeper that provides the authorization code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the OmniAuth docs, a **provider** is an entity that provides an OAuth endpoint, that your users can use to log in to your application. [The list of OmniAuth providers](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies) includes the main players you'd expect: Facebook, Google and Twitter. This wiki page is actually a bit confusing since sometimes it uses the word "provider" and other times it uses the word "strategy".

As for Doorkeeper, it's a gem that allows you to [create your own OAuth endpoint](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Create-a-OmniAuth-strategy-for-your-provider). You generally use this gem if you have a microservices architecture. You have one application responsible for authentication that provides an OAuth endpoint and then you have other several applications that use this endpoint to authenticate their users.

Comment: So is strategy and provider the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, same thing.